# Access hidden account from login screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

After I set a blank password to my admin account, My account icon was removed from login screen and I'm completely locked out of my Mac. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have auto-login enabled for this user? If so you can probably reboot and get back in.

If you see the 'Other' user at the Login Window you can use that, too.

If all else fails you try ssh'ing in from another system (`ssh user@computer.local`) or booting up in single user mode (`Command-S` on startup).

Answer (score 2):

Hold down SHift+Option+Down Arrow+Return to reveal the username and password field at the login screen.

Comment: The actual procedure is to tap any arrow key to move focus to the list of accounts, then option-return — not holding shift which is for disabling login items and not holding down arrow.